# PostgreSQL default values in QGIS 2.8.2

Tags: postgis, postgresql, qgis-2.8

I think the issue outlined in this question [PostgreSQL default values in QGIS 2.8.1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138738/postgresql-default-values-in-qgis-2-8-1/139118#139118) and ticket #12391 is not fully solved yet. Negative numeric default values, and dates are not used by QGIS 2.8.2 correctly. When I work on them and save the layer, the default values were not computed, and the NOT NULL constraints block me. 2.6 works.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE bla
(
  vres double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT (-32768.0),
  startvalid date NOT NULL DEFAULT '2001-01-01'::date
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with char default values. Varchar, boolean and numeric are ok.
Qgis version 2.8.5

```
drop table prova;
create table prova (
    gid serial primary key,
    test_bo varchar(100) default 'false' not null,
    test_bo2  varchar(100) default 'false' not null,
    geom geometry(Linestring,32632)
    );
```

Works

```
drop table prova2;
create table prova2 (
    gid serial primary key,
    test_bo char(1) default 'f' not null,
    test_bo2  char(1) default 'f' not null,
    geom geometry(Linestring,32632)
    );
```

Not working. test_bo and test_bo2 are NULL instead of default value.