# What PostgreSQL version to use with QGIS 2.8 (on Linux/Fedora 21)

Tags: qgis, postgresql, qgis-2.8, fedora

I'm looking to install QGIS on my Linux/Fedora 21 laptop.

QGIS ver. 2.8 seems to be the new/stable version (Feb. 2016)

What PostgreSQL version should I use with that?

Comment: See the compatible list https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=postgis

Comment: This do not answer the question: Which PostgreSQL version goes best with Qgis 2.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the following link. this might help you. Good Luck

[PostgreSQL default values in QGIS 2.8.1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138738/postgresql-default-values-in-qgis-2-8-1/139118#139118)

"QGIS 2.8.1, OsGeo4W built against PostgreSQL Client Version 8.3.10,"

Comment: Fedora 21 support, by default, PostgreSQL 9.3.9 / PostGIS 2.1.7 / QGIS 2.6 - I was just wandering if I could install QGIS 2.8, and then wandering what PostgreSQL to put with that. But I think all rather stick with the default versions, for now...

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing from binaries (rpm), then you should just let the package manager install the recommended version.

If you are building from source, or are just curious otherwise, the absolute minimum PostgreSQL version for QGIS 2.8 appears to be PostgreSQL 8.0, as documented in the [build instructions](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/release-2_8/INSTALL):

> Optional dependencies:
>
> - for postgis support and SPIT plugin - PostgreSQL >= 8.0.x

The 'best' version will depend on your situation. Newer versions may have more functionality or bug fixes, but if you already have an older version setup and running it may be preferable to use it instead.